# How can I inherit C#'s summary in another class? (like inheriting Javadoc)

Tags: c#, javadoc, summary

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [.NET xml docs - inheriting documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/311363/net-xml-docs-inheriting-documentation)

Can I use something like Javadoc's `{@inheritDoc}` in C#.NET ?

F.e. I write summary for interface method and method of implemented class does exactly what I wrote there, so I am copy+pasting atm. which doesn't seem very wise.

Thanks

Comment: yup, I see ... actually it looks like they are naturally inherited

Answer (score 5):

You can use [Xtensive.MSBuildTasks](http://www.x-tensive.com/Downloads/?Path=Freeware%5CXtensive.MSBuildTasks) (broken link) to automatically copy the documentation for you.

Another option is [Sandcastle](https://github.com/EWSoftware/SHFB) that has the `<inheritdoc />` tag.

Comment: +1 for the <inheritdoc /> tag. Further explanation about this topic: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1080418/383129

Answer (score 2):

There's an add-on called GhostDoc, which allows you to copy the text with a simple keystroke.

http://submain.com/products/ghostdoc.aspx