# Can I propagate XML documentation from an interface to its implementation?

Tags: visual-studio, resharper, xml-documentation

I need to propagate XML documentation from a base class to derivative(s) or from an interface to implementation(s).

Can I do this using Resharper?

Answer (score 20):

Yes you can.

If you're yet to implement/override members, then in a derived class or interface implementation, click <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ins</kbd>, choose "Overriding members" or "Implement missing members". In the wizard that displays afterwards, choose members to implement/override, and make sure to select "Copy XML documentation".

Alternatively, if you already have an overridden or implemented member in place, press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> on the overridden/implemented member, and select "Copy comments from base".

Comment: Wouldn't this requires me to update all documentation on all implementing methods if I update the interface documentation? Isn't there a better way to do this?

Comment: This would indeed require updating documentation on all implementing members but isn't that what you're looking for when you choose to maintain implementation-specific documentation?

Answer (score 1):

Starting from 2016.2 EAP 9, ReSharper supports the `<inheritdoc />` tag ([RSRP-33352](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-33352)). You will see the *accumulated* documentation using QuickDoc (default on <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>).

The *Members Generation* option page has been extended by another option to automatically add that tag to any generated member. You will also have a context action on members, which don't have a documentation yet.

[image]

I can also recommend the [XmlDoc Inspections plugin](https://github.com/ulrichb/XmlDocInspections#readme), which is somehow related to the topic.