# Can Resharper Copy XML Comments from Base Class

Tags: resharper

I have a class that i am inheriting from and the methods i override should have the same comments as the base. Does resharper have an option to copy them?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In addition to the above mentioned context action, which I find fairly tedious to apply for each inherited member, you can also configure ReSharper to "pull down" comments by default when implementing a base class or interface.

To do this, from the ReSharper main menu go to `Options | Code Editing | Member Generation | Other Options` inside here you will see an option to *Copy XML documentation from overridden members*, if you check this option ReSharper will automatically copy all inherited documentation for you.

[image]

Comment: As of 2016.2 you can also set it to add <inheritdoc/> instead. If that's your thing.

Answer (score 9):

Since version 3.0 of ReSharper, you should have a [context action](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/webhelp/Reference__Options__Languages__CSharp__Context_Actions.html) available to do this, **Copy comments from base**. If it doesn't appear to be available, make sure it's checked in `ReSharper | Options | Languages | C# | Context Actions`.

Comment: This seems to be per member, is there a way to do it for all members in a class?

Answer (score 2):

Let your overridden methods uncommented. So R# short help (Ctrl+Shift+F1) will automatically show the help of base class member.

Answer (score 1):

This is a duplicate of [Can I propagate XML documentation from an interface to its implementation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6042597/can-i-propagate-documentation-from-interface-to-it-implementation)

[Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6045093/1037948):  press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ins</kbd> from each method name, choose "Copy comments from base".  As [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7187345/1037948) indicates, you must have this option enabled.

Answer (score 1):

This is an older question, but I thought I'll add the point that resharper has support for the tag

```
     /// <inheritdoc />
```

With this it the comment of the interface is also shown in the tooltip in intellisense.

Comment: Intellisense does not recognize this tag for me in Visual Studio Community 2017.

Comment: You need to have Resharper installed for this to work.

Comment: I have it installed!

Comment: Which version and what VS?

Comment: I just updated to the latest Resharper version (2017.1.3), it previously was 2017.1.2. I can't seem to find any related options except for adding the value. Visual Studios is Community 2017. And it seems very hard to Google...

Comment: It seems like it does not always show up. When hovering over the item, it does not show up, when going through the auto-complete it is however shown. It is however always shown here even if you do not include the `<inheritdoc />` tag.

Comment: I see. Maybe I just use the use cases who are supported.

Answer (score 0):

I built a tool to post-process the XML documentation files adding support for the <inheritdoc/> tag.

While it doesn't help with Intellisense in source code, it does allow the modified XML documentation files to be included in a NuGet package and therefore works with Intellisense in referenced NuGet packages.

Go to www.inheritdoc.io for more info (free version available).