# Overriding a virtual method from within an inherited class but keep the comments of the base class

Tags: c#, comments

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Comment Inheritance for C# (actually any language)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/342964/comment-inheritance-for-c-sharp-actually-any-language)

In my application, my base class clearly defines the purpose of each virtual method.

When I inherit my base class and override the virtual methods, I'm having to re-type the comments.

Now, I know why it doesn't copy the comments by default and it makes sense but as I have many classes inheriting from my base class it's getting tiresome to copy the entire XML comments to add an additional `<para>` to the bottom of the comments.

Is this just the way it is?

Comment: Possibly related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/342964/comment-inheritance-for-c-sharp-actually-any-language

Comment: @UweKeim - agreed - +1 for giving me the answer and for letting me know I clearly didn't look hard enough  :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [ReSharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/). Whenever you implement any interface it will bring over the XML comments as well (if you so choose).

Comment: Ah, I have this and it doesn't (although I'm on version 6 I think). May be it needs to be switched on. Thank you.

Comment: If you need help, try looking here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6042597/can-i-propagate-documentation-from-interface-to-it-implementation