# Inherit constructor documentation in C#?

Tags: c#, exception, inheritance

i have an custom exception class in c#:

```
public class InformationException : Exception {}
```

Now of course this doesn't work, because the exception has no constructors.

Just making sure: i ***really*** have to add them myself? :

```
public class InformationException : Exception
{
    public InformationException() : base() {}
    public InformationException(string message): base(message) {}
    public InformationException(string message, Exception innerException) : base(message, innerException) {}
}
```

But then in order for the class to actually be useful i have to add the docs:

```
public class InformationException : Exception
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the System.Exception class.
    /// </summary>
    public InformationException() : base() {}

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the System.Exception class with a specified error message.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="message"> The message that describes the error.</param>
    public InformationException(string message): base(message) {}

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the System.Exception class with a specified error message and a reference to the inner exception that is the cause of this exception.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="message"> The error message that explains the reason for the exception.</param>
    /// <param name="innerException">The exception that is the cause of the current exception, or a null reference 
    /// (Nothing in Visual Basic) if no inner exception is specified.</param>
    public InformationException(string message, Exception innerException) : base(message, innerException) {}
}
```

Which i now have to repeat for:

```
public class ClientException : InformationException { }

public class BusinessRuleException : InformationException { }

public class InvisibleException : Exception { }

public class ProgrammerException : InvisibleException { }
```

There hasn't been any changes in C# [in the last 3 years](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/223058/how-to-inherit-constructors) that i missed? This is still the ***intended*** way to inherit classes?

---

**Update**: Whoops, turns out you also have to provide the protected constructor:

```
public class InformationException : Exception
{
    public InformationException() : base() {}
    public InformationException(string message): base(message) {}

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the System.Exception class with serialized data.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="info">The System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationInfo that holds the serialized
    /// object data about the exception being thrown.</param>
    /// <param name="context">The System.Runtime.Serialization.StreamingContext that contains contextual
    /// information about the source or destination.</param>
    /// <exception cref="System.ArgumentNullException">The info parameter is null</exception>
    /// <exception cref="System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException">The class name is null or System.Exception.HResult is zero (0).</exception>
    protected InformationException(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context);

    protected Exception(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context): base(info, context) {}
    public InformationException(string message, Exception innerException) : base(message, innerException) {}
}
```

Comment: Define the meaning of "of course this doesn't work," because of course it does. Whether or not it is *useful* is another matter.

Comment: Almost an exact duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/426484/why-are-constructors-not-inherited

Comment: @ChrisWue Yes, i was wondering if there has been any developments in the C# language since 2009. Or more specifically, to solve my problem, is there some sort of `<summary base><summary>` syntax

Comment: Alex Yakunin wrote: "I have a better answer: FiXml.". Not sure if it solves your specific problem, but it's certainly conceptually cleaner than duplicating the comments in the source.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/311717/373706) you can use [GhostDoc](http://submain.com/products/ghostdoc.aspx)

Comment: I agree, but if that is what the OP wants then there is something out there.

Comment: @aqwet If a person wants to throw an exception, they're going to need a way to create it...(?)

Answer (score 3):

```
/// <inheritdoc />
```

seems to do the trick in Visual Studio 16.4, i.e.

```
/// <inheritdoc />
public ClientException(string message): base(message) {}
```

This only works for the parameters if they have the same name as the base constructor parameters, of course.